# Facebook Sharing Wordpress Page Not Found

Tags: php, wordpress, facebook

I'm having some issues when sharing links from my website (Boolerang) to Facebook. The issue is: When I share a role, I get this:

[image: Screenshot]

When I go here to the Facebook OG Object debugger and show existing information, it says:

> Time Scraped - 8 hours ago. Response Code: 404. Critical Errors That Must Be Fixed: Bad Response Code  URL returned a bad HTTP response code.

However, when I "fetch new scrape information", it updates, and the link can then be shared in its intended form forevermore, i.e.:

[image: Screenshot]

These symptoms lead me to believe that the issue is not access-related, but that's as far as I get.

Edit:

My robots.txt file looks like this - could this be the cause?

> User-agent: * Disallow: /wp-content/plugins/ Disallow: /wp-admin/
>   Disallow: /candidates Disallow: /my-account Disallow:
>   /past-applications Disallow: /manage-jobs Disallow: /resume

Comment: Is this a single issue, or does this happen regularly? If so, when/under what circumstances?

Comment: Hi @CBroe. This happens for every job that is posted. It throws up the error until you fetch new scrape information.

Comment: Do you have any social plugins, like a like button or FB comments, on those job pages? If so, are those already present in preview mode, when the article is only yet visible to the admin/editor? Those plugins would trigger Facebook to scrape the URL, and because of preview mode all the scraper would get in response is a probably a 404 (or 403, depending on system configuration.)

Comment: Hi @CBroe. Thanks for your comment. I literally had this thought myself last night! I have Jetpack installed - primarily for the Sharing feature. This is visible during the preview phase. 

Do you believe Facebook must be scraping the site at this time, and since it is not yet published it is causing issues?

Comment: Yes, Facebook will scrape a URL that it does not have cached already immediately, when one of their social plugins points to that URL.

Answer (score 0):

Please Try first of all this code put in `function.php`

```
<?php 
add_action('wp_head','add_meta_function');
function  add_meta_function(){
    if(is_single()){
        global $post;       
        echo '<meta property="og:url" content="'.get_permalink().'" />';
        echo '<meta property="og:image" content="xyz/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/4569952.png" />';
        echo '<meta property="og:title" content="'.get_the_title().'" />';  
        echo '<meta property="og:description" content="'.substr($post->post_content,0,100).'" />';
    }

}
?>
```

You Use this link `http://www.sharelinkgenerator.com/` and generator facebook link

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=PASS SHARE LINK">Share on Facebook</a>
```

Example

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>">Share on Facebook</a>
```

> OR USE

Nice this plugin for share post,sec,etc
https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-seo/ read guide 
after user this link

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>">Share on Facebook</a>
```